# How SQL transaction preserves data integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, client-server

Let's take a sales server which can sell books to multiple clients.

For example:

- book { id:1, quantity:10 }
- book { id:2, quantity:10 }

...and so on

- client 1 -> Add to Cart of book{id:1,quantity:6}
- client 2 -> Add to Cart of book{id:1,quantity:7}

When the client clicks the buy button sales server, checks this condition:

```
if(buy.quantity <= available.quantity) { //available is freshly fetched from db
   sell();
} else {
   fail();
}
```

Now consider this case:

`client2` check this buy condition and is proceeding to `sell()` method.

Meanwhile `client1` also checked the buy condition and finished `sell()`..

so now available will be only `4`

..on the other hand `client2` have already passed the buy condition and is halfway executing the `sell()` condition so after `sell()` of `client2` there will be `-3`.

How this can be prevented?

How can a transaction help in this case?

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: I am newbie to data base

Comment: then your question is not related  to a specific db?

Comment: @scaisEdge sql server..but you can also tell me a generic solution. i want to know how things work internally

Comment: Aside: In some cases the issue can be avoided entirely, e.g. by using an `update` statement with an `output` clause and a `case` expression in the `set` clause. The `case` expression can ensure that adequate inventory is available and the `output` clause makes the _before_ and _after_ values available, e.g. for generating a failure message ("Only 2 copies of Alice in Wonderland are available."). E.g.: `update Inventory set QtyAvailable -= case when @QtyOrdered <= QtyAvailable then @QtyOrdered else 0 end output deleted.QtyAvailable, inserted.QtyAvailable into @Results where ItemId = @ItemId;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a transaction isolation level that will acquire a shared lock when reading the stock level and hold this lock until the update is completed. This blocks the second transaction from running until the first transaction has completed preventing the scenario you discuss.

Have a look at the following Microsoft document for further explanation of the various isolation levels in SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels

Comment: >acquire a shared lock>>> is this shared lock is part of db or application server?? @ben

Comment: It's part of the database server. The database handles all locking dependant on which transaction isolation level is used.

Comment: One small doubt suppose a runtime error occurred in middle of transaction and I didn't handle it..then does that mean db will be locked forever or until jdbc connection got closed??@ben

Comment: No. It depends on the XACT_ABORT setting in SQL Server. When OFF (which is default), usually only the statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. When ON, when an error is encountered the whole transaction is rolled back. Either way, the locks are released when the transaction completes.

Comment: transaction end when i call `transaction.commit()` or `transaction.rollBack()` right?? I use` transaction.begin()//Lock accuired;` `read()//doneOK;` `write()//unhandled exception app terminate;` i did not add any try catch block. In this case what will happen to acquired lock??@Ben

Answer (score 1):

One should never use an explicit database transaction when user action is required during the transaction (e.g. add to cart, checkout).

A race condition can be avoided without a long-running explicit transaction by performing the calculation in T-SQL in an automatic (single statement) transaction. All statements execute in an automatic transaction by default. For this this to work in a concurrent environment, the update statement can use an optimistic concurrency check, comparing the original value retrieved from the database to the current value:

```
UPDATE dbo.Inventory
SET AvailableQuantity -= @BuyQuantity
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode
    AND AvailableQuantity = @OriginalAvailableQuantity;
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR(Transaction rejected - someone updated the row',16,1);
```

A [`rowversion` column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) can facilitate optimistic concurrency checks, which is especially useful when many columns are involved:

```
UPDATE dbo.Inventory
SET AvailableQuantity -= @BuyQuantity
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode
    AND RowVersionColumn = @OriginalRowVersionColumn;
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR(Transaction rejected - someone updated the row',16,1);
```

Without optimistic concurrency or overly pessimistic locking, you could add the business rule that quantity cannot become negative to the `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE dbo.Inventory
SET AvailableQuantity -= @BuyQuantity
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode
    AND AvailableQuantity -= @BuyQuantity >= 0;
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR(Transaction rejected - Available quantity may not be negative',16,1);
```

This simplified example is only to show some optimistic concurrency techniques. One can, and should, still use an explicit transactions when multiple statements are involved (e.g. all-or-none checkout of multiple items). A robust shopping cart system would need to consider abandoned or expired sessions and the implications on available quantity. One would need to add back inventory according to business rules.